# Create a new sheet within an existing spreadsheet google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is my third (and hopefully last) question for my current project.

The IF ELSE statement doesn't seem to be working properly in the following code:

```
function onFormSubmit() {
  // onFormSubmit
  // get submitted data
  var ss = 
SpreadsheetApp.openById("1UMSTyjYz2DMubBT54Q7a0V5ie5TAPYFZ2riqV5p93gE");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Submissions");
  var row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var Col = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var headings = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,Col).getValues();
  var lastRow = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, Col);
  var UnitNumber = sheet.getRange(row,3,Col).getValue(); 
  var newSheet = sheet.getRange(row,4,Col).getValue();
  // check if username has sheet

  if(ss.getSheetByName(UnitNumber)){
    var DrillSheet = ss.insertSheet(UnitNumber);
    // if not make
  } else {
  var DrillSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(UnitNumber); 
DrillSheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(1,1,1,Col).setValues(headings);
  }
  // Rename sheet to submission date
  DrillSheet.renameActiveSheet(newSheet);
  // copy submitted data to Drill sheet
  DrillSheet.appendRow(lastRow.getValues()[0]);
  DrillSheet.appendRow(['=CONCATENATE(B6," ",B5)']);
  DrillSheet.appendRow(['=TRANSPOSE(B1:2)']);
  //Hide top rows with raw data
  var hiderange = DrillSheet.getRange("A1:A3");
  DrillSheet.hideRow(hiderange);
  //Widen columns
  DrillSheet.setColumnWidth(1,390);
  DrillSheet.setColumnWidth(2,700);
}
```

The goal here is to create a new spreadsheet with the title 'UnitNumber' and sheet title as the submission date IF that spreadsheet doesn't already exist. If the 'UnitNumber' spreadsheet DOES exist, I would like to create a new sheet within that spreadsheet with the title as the submission date.

Currently it is creating a new spreadsheet every time.

Comment: Can you ask your different questions in different posts please?

Comment: Your code logic does not match your stated logic. The if/else does what your code asks it to do. A good first step here is to analyze your code, line by line, statement by statement, and explain to something nearby what that statement is doing - the arguments it needs, and the return value / side effect it has - if any. This will let you identify what your code is currently doing, and build enough familiarity with the Apps Script and JavaScript language that you can attempt to adjust your code logic to your stated logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing the problem with you try this code:

```
function onFormSubmit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1UMSTyjYz2DMubBT54Q7a0V5ie5TAPYFZ2riqV5p93gE");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Submissions");
  var row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var Col = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var headings = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,Col).getValues();
  var lastRow = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, Col);
  var UnitNumber = sheet.getRange(row,3).getValue(); 

  var fileExist = false;
  var drillSheet = null;
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("nameOfTheFolder").next();
  var files = folder.getFilesByName(UnitNumber);
  var file = null;
  while (files.hasNext())
  {
    fileExist = true;
    file = files.next();
    break;
  }
  if (fileExist)
  {
    drillSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
    drillSheet.renameActiveSheet("randomString") ;
  }
  else
  {
    drillSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(UnitNumber);
    var ssID = drillSheet.getId();
    file = DriveApp.getFileById(ssID);
    file = file.makeCopy(UnitNumber, folder);
    DriveApp.getFileById(ssID).setTrashed(true);
    drillSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
    drillSheet.renameActiveSheet("randomString");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks JSmith, my apologies for the lateness of this response - got caught up with a different task. Unfortunately I just tired this and it does the same thing - creates a new spreadsheet every time. Do you have any other input? Thanks again.

Comment: @ColinGrant sure but I would prefer be on the spreadsheet as it is where the modification takes place...

Answer (score 0):

To answer your last question, once you create a folder and share (the entire folder) with a list of people, any file that you subsequently place in that folder will automatically be shared with those people.

Comment: Only one issue should be asked in a question. You should not attempt to answer additional questions that are unrelated to the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed code that works as I intended. Much thanks to [@JSmith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1713208/jsmith) for helping me through - I could not have done this without you!

```
function onFormSubmit() {
  // onFormSubmit
  // get submitted data and set variables
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("some id");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Submissions");
  var row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var Col = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var headings = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, Col).getValues();
  var lastRow = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, Col);
  var UnitNumber = sheet.getRange(row, 3).getValue(); 
  var newSheet = sheet.getRange(row, 4, Col).getValue();
  var fileExist = false;
  var drillSheet = null;
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Fraser Drill Inspections").next();
  var files = folder.getFilesByName(UnitNumber);
  var file = null;
  // check if Drill has sheet
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    fileExist = true;
    file = files.next();
    break;
  }
  if (fileExist) //If spreadsheet exists, insert new sheet
  {
    drillSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
    drillSheet.insertSheet("" + newSheet);
  }
  else //create new spreadsheet if one doesn't exist
  {
    drillSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(UnitNumber);
    var ssID = drillSheet.getId();
    file = DriveApp.getFileById(ssID).makeCopy(UnitNumber, folder);
    DriveApp.getFileById(ssID).setTrashed(true);
    drillSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
    drillSheet.renameActiveSheet(newSheet);
  }
  // copy submitted data to Drill sheet
  drillSheet.getSheetByName(newSheet).getRange(1, 1, 1, Col).setValues(headings);
  drillSheet.appendRow(lastRow.getValues()[0]);
  drillSheet.appendRow(['=CONCATENATE(B6, " ", B5)']);
  drillSheet.appendRow(['=TRANSPOSE(B1:2)']);
  //Hide top rows with raw data
  var hiderange = drillSheet.getRange("A1:A3");
  drillSheet.hideRow(hiderange);
  //Widen columns
  drillSheet.setColumnWidth(1, 390);
  drillSheet.setColumnWidth(2, 700);
}
```